# Internal server error on repo.fusesource link

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I'm trying to download the below dependencies from http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource/10.2.0.3/ and it gives the below error.
Internal Server Error - Read Reference #3.4618ae8c.1515079103.3708303

The dependency that I'm trying to download is

> oracle.jdbc.pool
>      OracleDataSource
>      ${oracle-datasource-version}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource/10.2.0.3/ I have a 404 now. I think that the "Internal Server Error" was during an outage of the repository.

The oracle JDBC datasource artefact are not on this repository (for legal reason I think).
Please have a look to https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides

regards,